# CrystalDiskInfo Caution Error

Tags: external-hard-drive, storage, bad-sectors, crystaldiskinfo

I have checked my external HDD using Crystaldiskinfo.After I copied some files to the HDD Reallocated sectors count increased to 3360 from 3352 in Raw Values sector.What does this means? Should I buy a new HDD?

- Before copying files:

[image: Before copying files]

- After copying files:

[image: After copying files]

Comment: Use `smartctl` directly, as CrystalDisk doesn't accurately show values _(your HDD temp is not 100C)_. The main values to pay attention to for health are `Uncorrectable Sector Count`, Hardware errors section, the self-test log, and the `Power-On Hours`. Download [`smartmontools`](https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/Download#InstalltheWindowspackage) → `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>` → Run short test: `smartctl -t short /dev/<disk>` → Get disk status again: `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>` → Run long test _(takes several hours)_: `smartctl -t long /dev/<disk>` → Re-check disk info once finished

Comment: _Cont'd...)_ Until S.M.A.R.T values are directly polled via `smartctl` there's no way to accurately determine what the values are. Reallocated sectors simply means a read/write failure has occurred, not that it occurred due to hardware damage _(bad SATA cable, transient issue with SATA cable shielding resulting in data corruption, motherboard connector, etc. can all cause read/write errors)_. When physical [hardware] damage occurs, it's seen in the `Uncorrectable sector count`, hardware errors section _(between numerical values and self-test log sections)_, and self-test log section.